# how do i pass a JSON factory into a function?

Tags: javascript, wookmark

I'm using https://github.com/GBKS/Wookmark-jQuery to do some dynamic layout, i'm also attaching a function on window resize:

```
var $windowWidth = $window.width();
var options = {
        itemWidth: 100, 
        autoResize: true, 
        container: $('#tiles'), 
        offset: 5, 
        outerOffset: 0, 
        flexibleWidth: '30%' 
    };

if ($windowWidth >= 768 && $windowWidth <= 1200) {
    options.itemsize = 200;
    options.offset = 7;
} else if ($windowWidth > 1200) {  
    options.itemsize = 300;
    options.offset = 10;
}

$('#tiles li').woodmark(options); <-- this is fine
```

but i want to create a function to return the properties:

```
function getOptions() {
    var $windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var sizes = {
       itemsize: 100,
       offset: 5,
       autoResize: true, 
       outerOffset: 0,
       flexibleWidth: '30%' 
       }; 

    if ($windowWidth >= 768 && $windowWidth <= 1200) {
        sizes.itemsize = 200;
        sizes.offset = 7;
    } else if ($windowWidth > 1200) {
        sizes.itemsize = 300;
        sizes.offset = 10;
    }
   return sizes;
}

$('#tiles li').wookmark(getOptions); <-- doesn't work
$('#tiles li').wookmark(function() { getOptions }); <-- doesn't work
```

all the code samples in wookmark are done as a jquery plugin, and normal breakpoint doesn't work in chrome inspector..

Comment: What's "wookmark" or "woodmark"?

Comment: @RocketHazmat `wookmark` appears to be a jquery plugin for saving images

Comment: You're not executing the function... Do `$('#tiles li').wookmark(getOptions());`

Comment: Have you tried `$('#tiles li').wookmark(getOptions());`?  I'm assuming `wookmark` wants an object, not a function.  You need to call `getOptions` to get the object from it.  `wookmark` probably isn't programmed to call the function for you.

Comment: P.S. This has nothing to do with JSON.  JSON is a data transport format (like XML or CSV).  You don't have a "JSON factory" here.  You are creating a JavaScript object, not a JSON string.

Comment: @RocketHazmat you are right, more like a javascript object literal?

Comment: @LeeGary: Yeah, an object literal.  I'm just a bit picky about terminology, sorry :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `.wookmark()` an object, not a function.  When called, `getOptions()` returns an object.  When you do `$('#tiles li').wookmark(getOptions);`, the plugin has no idea what to do with the function you passed it, it wanted an object.

Try this:

```
$('#tiles li').wookmark(getOptions());
```